# Trying to understand p-adic logarithm map in elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

Im following these slides from "An Introduction to the Theory of Elliptic Curves" http://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf,
but I'm having some difficulty understanding how the ECDLP can be solved in anomalous curves.

On the slides it says: "If #E(Fp) = p, then there is a “p-adic logarithm map” that gives an easily computed homomorphism
logp-adic : E(Fp) -> Z/pZ. It is easy to solve the discrete logarithm problem in Z/pZ, so if #E(Fp) = p, then we can solve
ECDLP in time O(log p)."

But I'm having trouble understanding some concepts. I understand that there exists an homomorphism between the elliptic curve E(Fp)
and the ring of integers Z/pZ. I might be wrong but from what I understand this homomorphism is map phi that satisfies this properties

- phi(O) = 0
- phi(P + Q) = phi(P) + phi(Q)
- phi(kP) = k.phi(P)

What I don't understand is why is it easy to solve the discrete logarithm problem in Z/pZ. Isn't the Diffie Hellman key exchange based on the
difficulty of computing discrete logarithms?

But even assuming that it is easy do solve the DLP in Z/pZ, how could I get to the solution to the ECDLP assuming I have the solution to the DLP?

Finally, does anyone know any books or papers where I can read more about this? I tried looking but didnt find anything

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021935/what-is-p-adic-logarithmic-map-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-compute-it

Comment: The solution process is very simple as noted on slides 3 and 53, we can compute inverses mod $p$ using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and then note that $k\equiv\phi(kP)\phi(P)^{-1}\pmod p$. My favourite introduction to anomalous curves is [Elliptic Tales](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691151199/elliptic-tales) by Ash and Gross chapter 9 section 3. It provides a nice step-by-step example computation of the map.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is why is it easy to solve the discrete logarithm problem in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Isn't the Diffie Hellman key exchange based on the difficulty of computing discrete logarithms?

In the *additive group* $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, DLOG is equivalent to computing a modular inverse, which is efficient.
I highly suspect the target of the $p$-adic logarithm is this *additive* group, as

- the slides use different notation for multiplicative groups,
- you are right --- if it were a multiplicative group DLOG wouldn't be easy, and
- logarithms convert multiplication into addition, so the group operation in the codomain of a logarithm should really be addition.

> But even assuming that it is easy do solve the DLP in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, how could I get to the solution to the ECDLP assuming I have the solution to the DLP?

In general, given an efficiently computable injective homomorphism $\phi: G\to G'$, if DLOG is easy in $G'$, then it is easy in $G$.
This is because, given $t = g^a$, one can

1. compute $\phi(t) = \phi(g^a) = \phi(g)^a$
2. compute the discrete logarithm of $\phi(t)$ to recover $a$.

If $\phi$ isn't an injection you might run into some issues/have to do some more work, but the existence of such a homomorphism is good for attackers generically.
I think pairing-based cryptography has more examples of such things if you're interested in other examples, but don't know details myself.